# Check box add date in org mode

Tags: org-mode, list

I have a book list contained which will be read or had done. Like this

```
* English books [0/2]
  - [ ] bible
  - [ ]
```

When I use C-c C-c to check, is it possible to add date behind or add low level automatically.

```
* English books [1/2]
  - [X] bible   :03/22/2016
  - [ ]
```

Or

```
* English books [1/2]
  - [X] bible
     - DONE:03/22/2016
  - [ ]
```

Or

```
* English books [1/2]
  - [X] bible
   :PROPERTIES:
   :DONE:03/22/2016
   :END: 
  - [ ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.

```el
(defun date-hook-fn ()
  (goto-char (line-end-position))
  (insert (format-time-string " :%m/%d/%Y")))

(add-hook 'org-checkbox-statistics-hook 'date-hook-fn)
```